# Is Concrete Mathematics is a prerequisite to solve exercises of mathematics preliminary of TAOCP

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I am reading the The Art of Computer programming. I have some background of number theory not too much, may be that's why I could not able to solve all the exercises myself. And I hate to look at the solution, when I could not come up with the solution when I try to solve an exercise.

It's really taking time to solve all the exercises of chapter 1. When I don't know a concept, I had to search through the web. I am pretty sure I'll forget those soon. May be there is not enough text for mathematics preliminary, so that I could get the hang of it or may be I'm stupid.

If I read concrete mathematics, will I be able to solve the exercises by myself ? Are the concepts provided in concrete mathematics serves as a prerequisites for the mathematics preliminary of TAOCP ?

Comment: I don't think anyone should expect to solve _all_ the exercises in TAOCP ...

Comment: Do you mean the book "Concrete Mathematics" ? If it is that, IMHO, no: it will take you a huge number of hours to take some profit out of this (very good) book which has in fact a rather limited scope compared to what is really needed for (math oriented) computer science. You have much better to do: diving into TAOCP directly, looking at this, trying that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Concrete Mathematics* definitely covers **all** the math background necessary to deal with *The Art of Computer Programming*... **and much, much more!** In fact, I'd say that studying *Concrete Mathematics* simply as a means to understand *The Art of Computer Programming* is like using a sledgehammer to squash a mosquito.

On the other hand, the most difficult problems in *The Art of Computer Programming* (and in computer science in general) require some facility with mathematics that no amount of study will give you. No matter whether you have a sledgehammer, or just your hand, if you are not quick enough the mosquito will elude you.

But note that you don't need to solve **every** single problem in *The Art of Computer Programming* to profit from reading it, just like you don't need to win every single chess match you play to be a strong chess player.